# the return built-in

Tags: shell, posix, shell-builtin

According to the [Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/utilities/return.html),

> [t]he return utility shall cause the shell to stop executing the current
>   function or dot script. If the shell is not currently executing a
>   function or dot script, the results are unspecified.

However, if you run the following snippet

```
func () {
    ( return 1 )
    return 0
}
func
echo $?
```

the output is `0` (I tried bash and dash, with the same result). So, it seems that `return` does not cause the shell to stop executing the current function, which would contradict the POSIX standard. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
( return 1 )
```

This runs in a subshell. It does terminate the subshell immediately, and if you  caught that shell's return code, it would be `1`. The function itself returns `0` on the line after that.

(See [Grouping Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01) in the Shell Command Language specification.)

Compare with the `{}` form that doesn't introduce a subshell:

```
#! /bin/sh

func () {
    ( return 42 )
    echo "One:   $?"
    { return 1; }
    echo "Two:   $?"
    return 2
}

func
echo "Three: $?"
```

Output (note the absence of "Two"):

```
One:   42
Three: 1
```

Comment: Correct, however sometimes it's not obvious that `return` is executed in a sub-shell, for example if it's inside a `while` loop that reads input from a pipe. From the POSIX spec, I would have expected `return` to exit the function even if the `return` itself is executed in a sub-shell.

Comment: There is absolutely no way for separate shell processes to communicate in the way you're describing. The only information returned to the shell from a subprocess are an exit code and the contents of standard output if you choose to capture it.